# incompatible types when assigning to type 'bignum' from type 'int'

Tags: c, struct, types, int

I have to square to huge numbers(some numbers larger than long long int). I am encountering the problem as **incompatible types when assigning to type 'bignum' from type 'int'** 
The code is given below with declaration as provided. Please do help me.

```
typedef struct {
char digits[MAXDIGITS]; /* represent the number */
int lastdigit; /* index of high-order digit */
} bignum;

bignum add_bignum(bignum a, bignum b);
bignum square(bignum x);

bignum square(bignum x){
bignum c;
.
.
.
return c;
}


bignum modified_fibo(int A,int B,int N){
bignum fibo[N-1];
int i;
fibo[0]=initialise(A);
fibo[1]=initialise(B);
bignum val;
for(i=2;i<N;i++){
    val = bignum_square(fibo[i-1]);
    fibo[i] = add_bignum(val,fibo[i-2]);
}   
return fibo[N-1];
}
```

I am encountering error in the line **val = bignum_square(fibo[i-1]);**

Comment: Can't you use an external library to deal with big numbers like https://gmplib.org

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `val = square(fibo[i-1]);`?

Comment: No I dont want to use external library. As it is prohibited.

Comment: `bignum square(bignum x){` There is extra `_` when you call function , but actual function does not have it .

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees a function call for a function that hasn't beend defined it implicitly declares one with return type `int`. You define a function

```
bignum square(bignum x);
```

but no

```
bignum bignum_square(bignum x);
```

so the compiler implicitly declares

```
int bignum_square(bignum x);
```

and you get an error because when the implicitly declared function is used here you assign the `int` to a `bignum`

```
val = bignum_square(fibo[i-1]);
```

As suggested in comments use the function you have defined

```
val = square(fibo[i-1]);
```

Comment: Compiling with `-Wall -Werror` would prevent this kind of mistake with a more explicit compiler diagnostic.